# luasql nil value

Tags: lua, luasql

I tried to follow the example at http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/examples.html

```
Lua 5.2.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2011 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require "luasql.postgres"
> env = assert (luasql.postgres())
stdin:1: attempt to index global 'luasql' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you actually [download and install it](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/index.html#download)?

Comment: To use Postgres you need to install Postgress, SQLLite dll is normally included and can be used directly

Comment: postresql is installed and luasql-postgres is installed with the proper paths to PGSQL_DIR and PGSQL_INCDIR

Comment: In Lua 5.2, `require` no longer defines globals. You need to save its return value as in @losinggeneration's answer.

Answer (score 9):

You could try

```
luasql = require "luasql.postgres"
env = assert (luasql.postgres())
```